# Trouble understanding CSS animations

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to wrap my head around the CSS animation property. In my current code, I have basically this structure:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The li's inside are generated via JS, and what I'd like to do is animate the expansion so it's not as abrupt. I attached

```
animation: 1s linear;
```

to the outermost div, but it doesn't animate. What I'm trying to do is as the `li`'s are added/removed, the height of the wrapper should animate instead of simply change. I've been looking through various docs and sites, but I can't figure out if I don't understand the property or if I'm using it wrong.

Comment: Please provide some css or description of the animation you seek.

Comment: This request makes me think I'm not understanding the animate property as well. I'll update the question, but basically, as the li's get added/removed, I'd like to animate the height of the wrapper. In this case, I'm not even positive which level to animate, as I suspect it'd affect them all?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's good to know the difference between [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) in CSS, and when to use each.

`transition` is used when you want to animate changes to either specific properties (`transition: opacity .5s, color .5s`), or all properties (`transition: all .5s`) as they are altered. This way, if you change a property like `opacity` via - for example - a CSS hover state, or JavaScript, that change will animate.

`animation` is used to set a [keyframe animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) to an element, where you predefine a sequence of steps that can affect one or more properties of that element.

The type of animation you're requesting - simply animating an element in/out as it is added or removed from the DOM - does not exist in CSS alone. However, many JavaScript libraries can intelligently add/remove CSS classes while an element is added/removed, allowing CSS animations to carry out.

With that said, there is a way we could decently animate in `<li>` elements with CSS alone, by having them start with a keyframe animation.

Here's a live demo where I'm doing just that by animating each new `<li>`'s height from `0` to `2em` (which I've specified as the `line-height`). Note that `width` and `height` can only transition to a specified value - not `auto`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('ul').append('<li>List Item</li>');
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  animation: grow 1s;
  line-height: 2em;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
  <button>Add to List</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yah, I'm using JS (angular) to do the add/remove functionality. And thanks for clarifying `transition` vs `animate`. I'm going to try `transition` in my current setup; that may be what I wanted. But the explanation really helps clarify what's going on.

Comment: Does adding a transition for height on the ul still result in it jumping to the new height (if the li height isn&#39;t animated)? If so Animating the height on the li (which could also be a transition?) is a nice solution. I think fading it in would work well too with each addition staggered.